Unable to connect Android ADB with my Windows Host machine
I am trying to install Android emulator with Android Studio on Windows 11.

When I do adb shell with my Windows host cmd, my emulator can ping 10.0.2.2 but I can not ping 8.8.8.8. However, when I start my virtual device, I can go on internet!

My virtual devices has eth0: 10.0.2.15/24 and wlan0: 10.0.2.16/24.
My Windows ip is: 192.168.1.46/24

From my Windows host and my Linux VM, I can not ping 10.0.2.2.

From my virtual device (with adb) I can not ping my Linux VM or my Windows machine.


I want to be able to ping 10.0.2.2, and be able to ping my Windows host (or Linux VM) with my virtual device.
I tried a different port, e.g.:
adb kill-server 
adb tcpip 5236 
adb connect 10.0.2.16:5236

I tried to enable all network settings with developer options.
I tried to activate somes rules with my firewall
I activated Hyper-V and Windows hypervisor platform (on Windows features)
